# How to setup fallback fonts in Pillow?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I'm looking for any possibility to specify more than one font in ImageFont.truetype(), as it works in browsers (font-family, fallback fonts etc). If it isn't realized in the library, working workaround will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe with a list of fonts and `try/except`

Comment: Unfortunately, pillow doesn't throw an exception in case of missing glyph in font.

Comment: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4808 is the same question